# How to send notification on boot completed?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcastreceiver

I've got the following class called AlarmNotificationReceiver. 
The idea is to send a notification when the device is turned out. Something seems to be wrong since this isn't happening. Any ideas why?

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){

             NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            builder.setContentTitle("HEY I WAS INITIALIZED!");
            builder.setContentText("Good luck");
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.alert_icon);
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
            builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.notif_red));

        //notification manager
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(1234, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the following lines to the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AlarmNotificationReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing creation of notification channel. You can create notification as follows:

```
public class AlarmNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction())){
            ...
            createNotificationChannel(context);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,1000);
            ...
        }
     }
     private void createNotificationChannel(final Context context) {
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            CharSequence name = "ChannelName";
            String description = "Channel description";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(1000, name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I'm using an emulator with Android 7.0, could that be the problem? My app has to support Android 6.0 and 7.0.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed is the boot receiver getting triggered?

Comment: I think it's not being triggered? Is there anything I could have forgotten? I'm powering off my "device" with the power off button at the side and then rerunning the app with the emulator. Maybe I'm not reallly rebooting the device and that's the issue.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed just put a simple log in `onReceive()` and check if its being executed.  Put it outside `if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(intent.getAction()))`

Comment: @Stackoverflowed have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` in your manifest?

Comment: @Stackoverflowed execute commeand `adb reboot` from command line and check if the broadcast receiver is working

Comment: thanks for your time and help. I went to the device manager tab and made a cold boot.

Comment: @Stackoverflowed No problem. Enjoy coding :-)